# Redirect does not work?

Tags: apache, redirect, lithium

I have a problem in the Apache config. On my localhost

```
return $this->redirect('ex::dashboard');
```

executes perfectly.

But when I upload the code to the server. It terminates with a blank page.

What could be the reason? I tried to debug.. but with no success.

I have access of the server and checked most of the PHP parameters.

```
'./configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-pdo' '--enable-bcmath' 
'--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' 
'--enable-libxml' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' 
'--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' 
'--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' 
'--with-gd' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' 
'--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' 
'--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' 
'--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mysql=/usr' 
'--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-openssl=/usr' 
'--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' 
'--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' 
'--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
```

There is one difference in

LocalHost

```
Server API  Apache 2.4 Handler Apache Lounge
```

Dedicated server

```
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
```

Will this make a difference?

The code:

```
https://github.com/nilamdoc/vc.co.uk/blob/master/app/controllers/SessionsController.php#L33
```

at L33 it should redirect to the dashboard page

I also tried

```
header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/ex/dashboard");
```

but it did not redirect

Answer (score 0):

Given the following:

> I also tried
>
> `header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/ex/dashboard");`
>
> but it did not redirect

...this is not a Lithium question.

Are you sure it's even Apache? This:

```
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
```

...does not seem to indicate.